# magento custom module keep throwing error even after deleting all files

Tags: magento-1.9, module, error, custom

i created a module in magento 1.9 CE to override list.php, and there was some issue, then i removed all the files for that module (the xml under module and all files under app/local/mycompany/), but the xml file keeps coming back with the following error:

```
    exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 
'Invalid block type: MyCompany_MyCustomModule' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php:595
```

there is no MyCustomerModule anymore, but the system keep throwing the exception.

thanks a lot.

**EDITED:**

I did the following:

added these files:

```
app/etc/modules/MyCompany_CatalogList.xml

app/code/local/MyCompany/Catalog/etc/config.xml

app/code/local/MyCompany/Catalog/Block/Product/List/list.php
```

Then I reload the product category page, no products show (there should be some products). Then i went to the the above directory and deleted all the files.

Every time i try to load the page again, got that exception, but all the files are gone. I am confused.

[image]

Comment: Clear magento cache and session then try

Comment: i did try that, but the error still exists, even i completely removed all files and did the cache/session clean up.

Comment: Did add any layout file with that module??

Comment: nope, thanks for you continue help, really appreciated. please see my edited content.

Comment: Did you use any cache in magento?

Comment: nope, i turned off Cache.

Comment: Can you show screenshot the error

Comment: added. please see original post.

Comment: Have you install Ames catalogproductlist module?

Comment: no, i don't see it under System->Advanced->Advanced

Comment: There is some file related to that module in layout file or phtml file

Comment: I will look into that once I get home. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: thank you Sundraram, there is a mistake in my config.xml, now it's all fixed. thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Magento cache is disabled, there's two things that would cause this.

- A proxy cache (like Varnish)
- A opcache with file stat disabled

To fix the former, purge Varnish. To fix the latter, restart the PHP process (NB. file stat should be enabled anyway, the performance difference is negligible)

Comment: Thanks Ben, I don't really get what you mean. What should I do with your suggestion?

Comment: Eek - I'm not really sure how to simplify it much more. Its probably best passing the comments on to your web host - they'll know how to interpret it.

Comment: thanks, just did. thanks to Meenakshi Sundaram R's troubleshooting as well.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your cache mechanisms, if files based just wipe `var/cache/`

Comment: i did, but it didn't help.